# Using Several Buttons In a Single Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 56 toggle buttons and 8 regular buttons on a single activity. The 8 buttons aren't an issue as I'm using a single onClickListener class with a switch case in it to determine what each does.

The problem comes with the 56 toggle buttons. I know I can do the same thing but a switch case with 56 cases seems like a poor way to handle things.

The toggle buttons are only used to set a boolean value so I'm assuming a way to do this would be passing in a value with the onCheckedChangedListener corresponding to the boolean it needs to change.

I'm new to android development so sample code and links are very helpful.

I'll post any relevant code that I have if needed but I think my explanation is good enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Beyond your question being a bit broad, having 56 buttons sounds like a bad user experience itself. These days, people rarely stay focused for more than a few seconds, so confronting users with 56 buttons might be a problem by itself already.

Comment: I agree it would be terrible UI for a general user, but this app will only be used by people with training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with one case.  Keep all your boolean values in a Map, and keep a map of the ids->values.  Then your OnCheckedChangeListener (not an OnClickListener) just needs to set the value in the hash map with that id.  If you want to separate the ids from the logic a bit more, keep a map of id->name and name->boolean.  Either way it ends up with one listener that can work for all 56 toggles without any ifs or case statements

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for, I asked about this in an android dev discord but wasn't sure how to implement it. Is this link what I'm looking for? [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map)